# How to disable ScalaDoc generation in dist task in Play 2.2.x (using project/build.scala)?

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.2, sbt-native-packager, scaladoc

Adding the following settings to the `build.sbt` file  of a Play 2.2.x app
does not disable Scaladoc generation. How can it be disabled?

```
play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
    .settings(scalaVersion := "2.10.3")
    .settings(jsSettings : _*)
    .settings(
        publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false,
        publishArtifact in packageDoc := false
    )
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Add the following settings to the Play project:

```
sources in (Compile,doc) := Seq.empty
publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false
```

With the change it should be as follows:

```
play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
    .settings(scalaVersion := "2.10.3")
    .settings(jsSettings : _*)
    .settings(
        publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false,
        publishArtifact in packageDoc := false,
        sources in (Compile,doc) := Seq.empty
    )
```

Thanks [@peter-hilton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670/peter-hilton) for the comment!

Comment: This seems to prevent creating the docs JAR for me: `settings(publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false)`, and the same with `packageSrc` for the sources.

Comment: Works for me with Play 2.3.2: https://github.com/guardian/gu-who/commit/340d42acdef8f0b1a085026d9fb5276976ac0607

Comment: Great answer. The official document goes a long way in how to include the stuff but not how to disable it.

The answer was not clear to me wheter to include play.Project... but in my case just having the two lines in the first code block of the post was all needed. Now I can build and stage my app under 30 seconds as opposed to 5 min! Thank you!