# Skip scaladoc when running 'dist' on a Play project

Tags: playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager, scaladoc

How can I stop scaladoc from running when executing 'dist' on a Play project (currently using Play 2.3.0)? As an example:

```
$ git clone --branch play-2.3.0 git@github.com:guardian/gu-who.git
$ cd gu-who
$ sbt clean dist
[info] Loading project definition from /tmp/gu-who/project
[info] Set current project to gu-who (in build file:/tmp/gu-who/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 20-Aug-2014 09:57:55
...
[info] Compiling 23 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /tmp/gu-who/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /tmp/gu-who/target/scala-2.10/api...
[info] Packaging /tmp/gu-who/target/gu-who-1.0-SNAPSHOT-assets.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
model contains 54 documentable templates
[info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
[info] Packaging /tmp/gu-who/target/scala-2.10/gu-who_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /tmp/gu-who/target/scala-2.10/gu-who_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] 
[info] Your package is ready in /tmp/gu-who/target/universal/gu-who-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
[info] 
[success] Total time: 20 s, completed 20-Aug-2014 09:58:15
```

The 'scaladoc' portion of that process takes about **12** of those 20 seconds. I don't want to run scaladoc *at all* (anyone doing work on this non-library project will be looking at the actual source code).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable ScalaDoc generation in dist task in Play 2.2.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461798/how-to-disable-scaladoc-generation-in-dist-task-in-play-2-2-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For newer versions of Play (I'm currently using 2.8.1), you'll have to add these settings to the project in `sbt` (or to every subproject):

```
Compile / doc / sources := Nil
Compile / packageDoc / publishArtifact  := false
```

(This is the new syntax from sbt 1.)

Answer (score 0):

On a project built with Play 2.1 I added the following setting to my sbt build file

```
...settings(sources in doc in Compile := List())
```

This removed the documentation creation completely.