# How to disable scaladoc generation in dist task in Play 2.2.x (using build.sbt)?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

Using java-play 2.2.1 and sbt 0.13.0, I have the same problem stated in [How to disable ScalaDoc generation in dist task in Play 2.2.x (using project/build.scala)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21461798/1305344), except that I use the (supposedly) standard `build.sbt` instead of `Build.scala`.

Is there a way of doing this with `build.sbt`? Or should I move to `Build.scala`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** What's inside `.settings` method calls should go straight to `build.sbt`.

As [build.sbt defines a `Seq[Setting[_]]`, i.e. it’s a list of Scala expressions, separated by blank lines, where each one becomes one element in the sequence.](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Basic-Def.html#How+build.sbt+defines+settings) it's similar to full build definitions in `project/*.scala` files using `.settings` call.

You should add the following to a `build.sbt`:

```
publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false

publishArtifact in packageDoc := false

sources in (Compile,doc) := Seq.empty
```